# FBRequestDelegate only works on AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to encapsulate all my Facebook interactions within a `FacebookFacade` class to keep things clean and tidy. I have an instance of the iOS SDK Facebook class within my `FacebookFacade`.

My problem is that when I make a Graph API call within the facade, such as:

```
    [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

The only method of `FBRequestDelegate` that gets called is `requestLoading:` and nothing else.  I have tried putting similar code in other places, like in controllers and other models, and there too not all of the `FBRequestDelegate` methods get called, only `requestLoading:`.

In fact the only way I can get the other `FBRequestDelegate` methods to be called is to put all my Facebook logic in the `AppDelegate` and make my `AppDelegate` the `FBRequestDelegate`.

Why is this the case? Am I missing something here? I definitely do not want to use the `AppDelegate` as my `FBRequestDelegate` as I don't want to confuse the purpose of the `AppDelegate`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem this afternoon. Finally solved it:
You HAVE TO make your FBRequest from the MAIN thread.
Otherwise underlying NSURLConnect (in facebook object) never starts.

Comment: Oh my god this just saved me. I have spent so long debugging this facebook request. Why is this not mentioned in their documentation?

Comment: I think it's more related to NSURLConnection and Run loops. But they should advise to perform graph requests on main thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can share your appDelegate with the other controllers in your application.

I solved this problem by importing my AppDelgate (which instantiates and allocates the facebook object in it) into my interface, i.e

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

interface MyViewController: UIViewController <FBRequestDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
```

This way, i can create a pointer to point to the delegate object and use the facebook methods in where i need to.

```
-(void) someFunction{
      MyAppDelgate *sharedAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
      [sharedAppDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self]; 
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: I tried this, the delegates in my view controller still don't get called!  How exactly did you setup your facebook in the delegate so you could use it in a view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the initial object is not being released while facebook is working in the background.  If it is, when facebook goes to call the delegate and finds it nil or catches an error, it will not call back.